# I'm stuck at determining the value of f(1) what it should be if $x \ne 1$ for the function f to be continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Given that $f(x)=\frac{3}{x-1} $. Then the domain must be $R-${1}.
$\lim_{x \to 1-} f(x) = -\infty \\$ 
And $\lim_{x \to 1+} f(x) = \infty$
Now i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Since the left hand limit and the right hand limit disagree, you cannot choose any value for $f(1)$ s.t. $f$ will be continuous.